# How to reduce the file size of a web banner image with Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-size, file-format, compression

I need to change the file size of an image I created in Photoshop without changing the dimensions for a banner ad on the web. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Save For Web
2. Set to JPG
3. Reduce image quality

Answer (score 1):

To add to Ryan's answer, it also depends on the image type, whether to use JPG or PNG.  Typically, anything with a photograph in it is best saved as a JPG, to give you the best filesize:quality ratio.  Designs without photos in them (logos, typography, icons, etc.) are best saved as PNG/GIF.

Click on the 2-Up option in the Save For Web panel.  This allows you to view the original version vs. the one you are saving for web.

[image: 2 Up]

Configure your options, keeping an eye on the quality of the image in the preview window.  Reduce the colors in a PNG/GIF and the quality in a JPG, until you have a good balance between small file size and quality.  You can also try playing with some of other options in this panel, to further reduce file size and improve appearance.

[image: Options]

Keep an eye on your estimated file size in the bottom left-hand corner of the window.

[image: file size]

You can sometimes get away with JPG qualities of 40-50 and PNG/GIF colors of 4, but it will be different for every image you save, so it involves a lot of trial and error, to find your balance.

Answer (score 0):

To not only help you with more than just getting your file-size issue addressed, but also help you improve your banner production method overall. I've created a template for you using the new art boards feature in Photoshop.

https://choiceomg.com/bat.psd (Click to download my .PSD template)

[image]

After you design your banners, go to:
File -> Export -> Export As

This will allow you to export your banners with full control over quality, file-size, dimensions, and file type.

Comment: Oh this is a nice resource!